# DLookup for multiple criteria within a date range in a separate table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Morning all,

I have a ms-access database with a form controlled entry into a table.

On input of values including a date, I'd like the table to pull in data from a separate table where the date falls within a certain range and has a distinguishing value.

For example;

If the date entered is today "15/1/19" and the chamber entered is "Frozen", look up to the separate table and return the name of the promo cycle where the chamber = "Frozen" and the date falls within the range of dates the promo cycle runs for.

Many Thanks

Comment: When should this action to retrieve the value happen? When pressing a button? When updating a specific field in the form? When saving the forms record? And if you were able to retrieve the described value from the second table, what should happen with it? Should it be set to a field value in the form?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
Dim Chamber As String
Dim TrueDate As Date
Dim TextDate As String
Dim PromoCycle As Variant

Chamber = "Frozen"
TrueDate = Date
TextDate = Format(TrueDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

PromoCycle = DLookup("[PromoCycle]", "YourTable", "[Chamber] = '" & Chamber & "' And #" & TextDate & "# Between [PromoStartDate] And [PromoEndDate]")
```